# 2 arrays: keep only elements with different value

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have 2 arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [fieldname] => banana
            [value] => yellow
        ) 
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [fieldname] => rome
            [value] => city
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [fieldname] => bla
            [value] => yes
        )
)
```

I want to create a new array that contains only elements where "id" is different. In other words I want to get this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [fieldname] => bla
            [value] => yes
        )

)
```

**[id] => 2** was the only different **[id]** so I keep it.

Said that I've already managed to achieve my goal with an inefficient pile of foreach, if statements and temp variables. I really don't want to use a wall of code for this very small thing so I started to look for a native PHP function with no success. What's the easiest way to get the result? Is it possible that I strictly need to use a foreach with so many if?

Comment: When you say different, are you talking about all the values being unique or only the id? Do you want to remove elements that have duplicates, both the original and the duplicate?

Comment: classic way to handle it is using array-search http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) with a function.

> Computes the difference of arrays by using a callback function for
>   data comparison.
>
> Returns an array containing all the values of the first array that are not
>   present in any of the other arguments.

---

The code:

```
// Setup two arrays as per your question
$array1 = array (

  '0' => array (
    'id' => '1',
    'fieldname' => 'banana',
    'value' => 'yellow',
  )

);

$array2 = array (

  '0' => array (
    'id' => '1',
    'fieldname' => 'rome',
    'value' => 'city',
  ),

  '1' => array (
    'id' => '2',
    'fieldname' => 'bla',
    'value' => 'yes',
  )

);

// Setup the callback comparison function
function arrayCompare($array2, $array1) {
    return $array2['id'] - $array1['id'];
}

// Use array_udiff() with the two arrays and the callback function
$arrayDiff = array_udiff($array2, $array1, 'arrayCompare');
print_r($arrayDiff);
```

The above code returns the following:

```
Array (

  [1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [fieldname] => bla
    [value] => yes
  )

)
```

Comment: Damin it true! Callback was the way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Not super short and it does use a temporary variable, so perhaps not what you were looking for. I've named the two arrays `one` and `two`.

```
$ids = array();
$result = array();

foreach ($one as $x) {
    $ids[$x['id']] = 1; //This way, isset($x['id']) vill return true
}

foreach ($two as $x) {
    if (!isset($ids[$x['id']])) {
        $result[] = $x;
    }
}
```

I would be surprised if there wasn't an even more compact way to do it.

**EDIT:** This is an alternative variant with nested for each. Not particularly short either.

```
$result = array();

foreach ($one as $x) {
    foreach ($two as $y) {
        if ($x['id'] == $y['id']) {
            //A match, lets try the next $x
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    //No matching id in $two
    $result[] = $x;
}
```